# Hibernate pair elements by foregin key

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables in my database:

`Wlasciciele`

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "wlasciciele", schema = "telefony", catalog = "projektjava")
    public class WlascicieleEntity{

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int id;

        private String imie_nazwisko;

        @OneToMany
        @JoinColumn(name = "wlasciciel")
        private List<TelefonyEntity> telefonyEntities = new ArrayList<>();

   //getters and setters

   }
```

And `Telefony`

```
  @Entity
@Table(name = "telefony", schema = "telefony", catalog = "projektjava")
public class TelefonyEntity{

    @Id
    private String numer;

    private String marka;
    private String model;
    private String typ;
    private int wlasciciel;

 //getters and setters
}
```

Tables are connected together by a one to many relation.

List of all `Wlasciciele` displayed as:

```
 @Override
    public List<WlascicieleEntity> listWlasciciele() {

        List<WlascicieleEntity> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        list = session.createQuery("from WlascicieleEntity").list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

        return list;
    }
```

My question. How do collections that kept the data from 2 tables? So that each `Wlasciciel` assigned a `Telefon`

Edit:
My solution:

```
 Map<List<WlascicieleEntity>,List<TelefonyEntity>> map = new HashMap<>();

        List<WlascicieleEntity> listaWlascicieli = new ArrayList<>();
        List<TelefonyEntity> listaTelefonow = new ArrayList<>();

        List wlasciciele = session.createQuery("FROM WlascicieleEntity ").list();
        for(Iterator iterator1 = wlasciciele.iterator(); iterator1.hasNext();){

            WlascicieleEntity wlascicieleEntity = (WlascicieleEntity) iterator1.next();
            System.out.print(" Imie: " + wlascicieleEntity.getImie_nazwisko());

            listaWlascicieli.add(wlascicieleEntity);

            List telefony = wlascicieleEntity.getTelefonyEntities();


            for(Iterator iterator2 = telefony.iterator(); iterator2.hasNext();){
                TelefonyEntity telefonyEnity = (TelefonyEntity) iterator2.next();
                System.out.println(" Telefon: " + telefonyEnity.getMarka());

                listaTelefonow.add(telefonyEnity);
            }
            map.put(listaWlascicieli,listaTelefonow);

            System.out.println("\n");
        }
```

I did this using the map and iterator. There is another possibility so as not to use the iterator class?

Comment: `"How do collections that kept the data from 2 tables?"` This is unintelligible English.  Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: I would like to hold a collection of values from the first table, along with their associated values in the second table.

Comment: First of all, why do you create transaction for read operations (listWlasciciele method)? Second, your 'wlasciciele' collection already has data from both tables, why do you want to create new one?

Comment: Ok, sorry I'm new in hibernate. I should remove `session.BeginTransaction()` yes? How do I get access `telefony` from `wlasciciele`. Using Object         `private List<TelefonyEntity> telefonyEntities = new ArrayList<>();` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to hold a collection of values from the first table, along with their associated values in the second table

So, you want a `List<WlascicieleEntity>` and you don't want a lazy exception to be thrown when iterating through the list of TelefonyEntity contained inside each `WlascicieleEntity`.

There are two solutions:

1. don't close the session until you have iterated through each list of TelefonyEntity: the lists will load themselves lazily.
2. fetch everything at once:

   ```
   public List<WlascicieleEntity> listWlasciciele() {

       Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
       session.beginTransaction();
       List<WlascicieleEntity> list = session.createQuery(
           "select distinct w from WlascicieleEntity w"
           + " left join fetch w.telefonyEntities").list();
       session.getTransaction().commit();
       session.close();

       return list;
   }
   ```

Comment: Can You explain 1.? Basically I do not want to use queries only everything to do with using objects. As I presented it in my solution.

Comment: Your first code snippet is correct, except trying to access the telephones of the returned wlascicieles will lead to an exception, because the session is closed. If you close the session AFTER you have done your job with the phones, you won't get any exception.